# Question title is missing in answer's timeline window title

Tags: bug, status-declined, timeline, window-title

When viewing the timeline of a question ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279172/timeline)), the title of the page contains the title of the question as well, e.g. using the given example:

> Timeline for Error viewing revisions list of an answer (Id = 279172) - Meta Stack Exchange

However, when viewing the timeline of an answer, the title is missing: ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279174/timeline))

> Timeline for  (Id = 279174) - Meta Stack Exchange

Screenshot:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed by adding the question title to answers timeline as well?

Comment: Arguably, answers don't have titles, so the page shouldn't show the title of the _question_ they are answering. The page title should allow you to distinguish between different tabs - something that wouldn't be true if things were implemented your way.

Comment: @Oded not asking to remove the ID, just add the title. So maybe "Timeline for answer (Id = 123456) on [question title here]"?

Comment: There is another bug (see linked post). Also I've upvoted this unfairly declined bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been changed at some point, so I guess it is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? Right now, for the timeline of a question, I see as the window title:

> Timeline for *question title* - *site name*

And, for the timeline of an answer, I see as the window title:

> Timeline for answer to *question title* by *username* - *site name*

The post IDs seem to have been removed from the window titles for the timelines of both, questions and answers.

Comment: Yes this was "fixed" when they changed the timeline view to match the moderators timeline, and added link to timeline. Forgot I posted this bug report lol.