# Timeline for answer has extra space character in HTML title section

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, russian-stackoverflow, timeline

On Stack Overflow in Russian we (OK, I) added French quotes, `«»`, around the title in transifex: [here](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/153937537?q=key%3A150435ce272d64612ac099ed05a1ee3c) and [here](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/153937618?q=key%3Ac7112131357000f634a16c427da3b21e).

Check here for example on site: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/891304/timeline

If you look into the HTML source you will see that there is an extra space character right after the opening quote (code 171):

> ```
> <title>Временная шкала для &#171; (Id = 891304)&#187; - Stack Overflow на русском</title>
> ```

> [image: title in browser]

This space has come from the strings concatenation (title + id), but in case of an answer there is no title (see here: *[Question title is missing in answer's timeline window title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279175/question-title-is-missing-in-answers-timeline-window-title)*)

In case of no quotes around tile, like on any SE site with an English interface, two sequential spaces are interpreted as a single one, and no visible defect is observed in browser. But it is still visible via the HTML source of course.

Answer (score 5):

This has now been fixed. The extra space has been removed.